# Voltage value at opamp exit

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]
This is an apparently simple opamp circuit that i cannot solve... The question is: is the voltage at blue probe the same as at green probe? (imagine no probes are there, they are just to locate voltage points). I can calculate current trough R2 and R3 but i do not know how to calculate current at opamp exit (between opamp and blue probe) with that value i could solve the problem easily... eventhough is it possible to solve it without that current value?

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the voltages given. This is a classical factor-1.3333 non-inverting amplifier circuit. When fed with 2.25V, the output should be 3.0V, and not 2.5V, as shown in the diagram.

Comment: What is the current through R4? Where is that current coming from? Where is it going to? How much current is needed by the thing that it's going to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *The question is: is the voltage at blue probe the same as at green
> probe?*

If there is no external load on the node that the green probe connects then yes, they will be the same voltage. This is because there is no current through R4 when there is no load at the green probe node.

> *I can calculate current trough R2 and R3 but i do not know how to
> calculate current at opamp exit*

The op-amp output current (in the absence of any load on the green node) *IS* the same current that flows through R2.

Comment: thanks that''s what i imagined, but was not sure... my professor tries to make questions confusing hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Of course the voltage on the blue probe is the same at the green probe because R4 has no current in it.

I think the opamp output voltage is 3.0V, not 2.5V.

None of the opamp output current is in R4.

Comment: yes, actually it is 3V ; the 2.5V it the voltage needed to light the probe...

Comment: If the "green probe" is actually a green 2.5V LED with its cathode connected to ground then the 4k resistor will feed it (3V - 2.5V)/4k ohms= 0.125mA making it extremely dim. Your opamp has no part number for us to see of it is powerful enough to burn out the "blue LED".